# How to count Multiply-Adds operations?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Given a defined Convolutional Neural Network, is there a function or method on how to compute the number of `Multiply-Adds` operations?

The term was introduced `MobileNetV2` paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf.

> We evaluate the trade-offs between accuracy, and number of operations
>   measured by **multiply-adds** (MAdd), as well as actual latency, and the
>   number of parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Counting the `Multiply-Add` operations is equivalent to calculating the FLOPs of a model. This can be achieved using the profiler from tensorflow.

```
flops = tf.profiler.profile(graph,\
     options=tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
print('FLOP = ', flops.total_float_ops)
```

Be sure to look at the caveats explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387561/how-to-calculate-the-flops-from-tfprof-in-tensorflow/50680858#50680858). Basically:

- The number of FLOPs calculated might include initialisation operations like Multiply-Add from initialising your weights with a Gaussian distribution for instance, you need to freeze the graph to rule those possibly irrelevant Multiply-Add operations,
- The Multiply-Add calculations from TensorFlow are approximate. An issue has been opened on this matter [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19746).

Comment: Any advice on how to get it to work on TF 2.0 models?

Comment: For TF 2.0 & Keras model, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525776/how-to-calculate-a-mobilenet-flops-in-keras

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about a function, but this website should help you keep track of MulAdd operations, The only caveat is you might need the prototxt file, but for popular architectures MulAdd operations are already listed

-https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/quickstart.html

Hope it helps.